# Swift Sniff Network Traffic With Raw Sockets

Tags: swift, sockets, network-programming, sniffing

I have been researching for hours on this. I cannot find a way to sniff network traffic (even without raw sockets) in Swift or Objective-C. If anyone could help that would save me more hours of headache. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't sniff it on iOS device itself, but you can use [remote virtual interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1176/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10001707-CH1-SECIOSPACKETTRACING)

Answer (score -3):

It is now possible to sniff network traffic with sockets on iOS devices using Apple's [Network Data Syndication API (docs)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204145). The new interface for content verification was added on 1/16/17 with the release of Swift 3.9.1.

Comment: Um, that's a link about your Apple ID being compromised.

Comment: @Bennett Apologies, I've found the correct link. Here's the link to Apple developer support. https://getsupport.apple.com/

Comment: That's to get support about an apple device.